# Get the chosen object to angular controller throught function

Tags: angularjs, select

I have one problem.
I need get the chosen object from select to angular controller throucght function in ng-change.
My view:

```
<select name="region" id="region_of_birth" class="form-control"
     ng-options="item.Id as item.Name for item in regionsList"
     ng-model="model.BornRegionId"
     ng-change="refreshBornDistricts(item)">
 <option></option>
```

Function in controller:

```
 $scope.refreshBornDistricts = function (item) {
     console.log(item);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected item is stored in model.BornRegionId

So just call this:

```
 $scope.refreshBornDistricts = function () {
     $scope.model.BornRegionId // = your selected ID
 };
```

Comment: I dont need to get BornRegionId i need get the others fields

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Angular blindly evals what is in ng-change, nor does it inject the currently value of the select object when it fires off the registered event.  So, I don't think you'll be able to explicitly refer to item.

The ng-change event does fire after the model changes propogate, so you could simply refer to the bound model in your refreshBornDistricts function

```
$scope.refreshBornDistricts = function () {
    console.log($scope.model.BornRegionId);
}
```